# xml парсинг(python). Как достать определенные объекты

Tags: python, xml, requests, beautiful-soup

Добрый день! Имеются вот такого рода данные(https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2 ссылка если что)

[image: xml]

Я написал код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

При запуске, я получаю ту же самую табличку, но не знаю как вытащить из нее первые 10 объектов и все их значения
[image: кнсл]

пробовал еще

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.contents[1])
```

Не помогло. Получается что под списком `[1]` я получаю полностью весь файл

Буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться

Comment: каким образом BeautifulSoup узнает какую именно информацию вы хотите получить. Не вставляйте текст в виде картинки. Явно приведите ожидаемый вывод прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs не подскажете тогда, какимо образом я могу открыть xml файл, который находится в сети и доступ к нему по ссылке? Пробовал много способов, все требуют локальное местонахождение(

Comment: код в вопросе уже читает xml из сети. Если это не ясно, то задайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться одним из [ответов на похожий вопрос (как преобразовать XML в словарь?) в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923963/5741205).

Для не очень больших XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from copy import copy

def dictify(r,root=True):
    if root:
        return {r.tag : dictify(r, False)}
    d=copy(r.attrib)
    if r.text:
        d["_text"]=r.text
    for x in r.findall("./*"):
        if x.tag not in d:
            d[x.tag]=[]
        d[x.tag].append(dictify(x,False))
    return d
```

Пример:

```
r = requests.get('https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=2')
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
d = dictify(root)
```

Результат:

```
In [114]: d
Out[114]:
{'wm.exchanger.response': {'BankRate': [{'_text': '59,2811',
    'direction': 'RUR/USD',
    'ratetype': '1'}],
  'WMExchnagerQuerys': [{'amountin': 'WMR',
    'amountout': 'WMZ',
    'inoutrate': 'WMR/WMZ',
    'outinrate': 'WMZ/WMR',
    'query': [{'allamountin': '36499,92',
      'amountin': '36499,92',
      'amountout': '588,62',
      'id': '27160894',
      'inoutrate': '62,0093',
      'outinrate': '0,0161',
      'procentbankrate': '+4,6',
      'querydate': '10.12.2017 18:01:14'},
     {'allamountin': '37042,82',
      'amountin': '542,9',
      'amountout': '8,76',
      'id': '27163373',
      'inoutrate': '61,9748',
      'outinrate': '0,0161',
      'procentbankrate': '+4,54',
      'querydate': '10.12.2017 20:50:02'},
     {'allamountin': '40260,53',
      'amountin': '3217,71',
      'amountout': '51,93',
      'id': '27163546',
      'inoutrate': '61,9624',
      'outinrate': '0,0161',
      'procentbankrate': '+4,52',
      'querydate': '10.12.2017 22:03:02'},
      ...
```